# Thymeleaf or Angular4 with Springboot

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular, thymeleaf

I've mostly worked with Springboot framework only with JSP to cover the things I need for the website part. Now, I've got a project to do that mostly revolves, if not all, around the website and I have a couple of questions. 
Just to be clear first, I don't have experience either with Thymeleaf or Angular so whichever I pick will be the first time (I think thymeleaf syntax would be easier for me to handle).

Ok so the main goal in my mind is not to render the whole page every time I load data from the backend, so I figure I would have like a header/content/footer parts where every time I click something only the content part would change. Also, I would like the possibility for a loader to show and go away when the content part is changing. This web application will need to be secure for users that register.

I've searched the web to investigate both frameworks, but can not seem to find the right answer so I can continue with my development

I do not mind creating separate REST services in later development if some other platform needs to hook up to the service if I decide to go with Thymeleaf.What do you guys think in what direction should I go, Thymeleaf or Angular? Any help and/or discussion would be much appreciated.

I am sorry if this seems like a general question, but I just need some basic guidelines to start with. Cheers!

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges. Front end single page app frameworks provide a much more robust user experience than a back end one will

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think transitioning to ThymeLeaf is probably going to be the easiest for you, but Angular is a great choice as well, and from there it is up to you. Would you rather use mostly expressions similar to JSTL expressions, but in Spring's SpEL language, then use ThymeLeaf, or would you rather use JavaScript, then use Angular. It just a user's preference for what you are doing.

The fragmenting portion (header, footer, body, etc..) is native to both frameworks. It just depends on which one you want to use. Whatever you go with, to load specific sections while not rendering the others, is going to require AJAX and for you to feel comfortable with how the template frameworks work.

I would suggest reading up on both of them to figure out which one you feel more comfortable with.

[Angular](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

[Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html)

Both of them have great documentation for beginners and the [Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/) and [Mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/) have good walkthrus for ThymeLeaf. Angular's documentation I found good enough on its own.

For a loader, you can do with simple CSS and JS. There is a ton of demos out there on how to do full screen loaders and how to turn them on or off with JS or CSS. [IHateTomatoes](https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/) has a good article about how to build a full screen loader, that has a No JS fallback option and should give you a good starting point.

Your point about it needing to be secure is a whole other monster. I would look into Spring Security. It's relatively straightforward, especially when using Spring Boot. If you want it can control the users session and assist in preventing session jacking, add CSRF to prevent cross site forgery, control permissions to urls and on down the line, or not. It all just depends.

Either way, don't randomly stab at security, it will end up in something that you feel is secure but it is not, which leaves you and your users in a very bad spot. Again, [Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/registration-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-security) has a great walkthru on the user registration and login process that can help get you started with Spring security and how to tie everything together.

Pretty high level answer, but hopefully gave you some good starting points and some resources.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and straight to the point answer. If both support fragmentation and both require Ajax I think in that case I will stick to Thymeleaf, because even if I know javascript I feel more comfortable with JSTL like expressions. Already have experience with spring security, just wanted to check if it is easier to use it with angular or thymeleaf, but I figure thymeleaf. Also thanks for the links I am going to need them!

Answer (score 3):

Build apps decoupling frontend from the backend.

Always build apps following the **"The API-first approach"**
The API-first approach involves setting up the foundation of your app, which is the application programming interface

**For me the differences between Thymeleaf and Angular:**

**Using Thymeleaf:**  You don't need to create Restful/web service endpoints on your frontend side because you just need to make calls to the backend from the frontend itself.

**Using Angular:** Besides of your Restful/ web service endpoints on your backend side, you have to build Restful/ web services endpoints on your frontend side because you don't want to expose direct access from Javascript code to the backend.

**Hope this helps and happy coding time!**